# MVC: How to get data from my database to show the data in a dropdownlist with viewmodel?

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, viewmodel

This is my Viewmodel

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Sname { get; set; }
    public string Cname { get; set; }
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public Question question { get; set; }
    public CoreValue corevalue { get; set; }
    public SubjectType subjecttype { get; set; }

}
```

and inside my view I have problems this code aint working:

```
@model NKI3.ViewModels.IndexViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sname)
</div>
</fieldset>
}
```

The error message I get is " No overload for method 'DropDownListFor takes 1 argument "

Whats the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public class AdminController : Controller
{
    AdminRepository AdminRep = new AdminRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Question> ListQuestions = AdminRep.GetAllQuestions();
        var model = new AdminIndexViewModel();  
        model.QuestionList = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in ListQuestions)
        {
            var QuestionViewModel = new QuestionViewModel();
            model.QuestionList.Add(QuestionViewModel);
            QuestionViewModel.QuestionText = item.QuestionText;
            QuestionViewModel.QuestionId = item.Id;
            QuestionViewModel.CoreValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (var CoreValues in item.CoreValue)
            {
                QuestionViewModel.CoreValues.Add(CoreValues.Name);
            }
            QuestionViewModel.SubjectTypes = new List<string>();
            foreach (var SubjectType in item.SubjectType)
            {
                QuestionViewModel.SubjectTypes.Add(SubjectType.Name);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.QuestionList) {
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionText)
    </td>
    <td>
    @string.Join(", ", item.SubjectTypes)
    </td>
    <td>
    @string.Join(", ", item.CoreValues)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", new { id = item.QuestionId}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", new { id = item.QuestionId })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing in the List that will populate the dropdown list see the example below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sname, ((IEnumerable<SNameList>)ViewBag.ListofSName).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Description),
                                                Value = option.Id.ToString(),
                                                Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.SName)
                                            }), "Choose...", new { @class = "full-width" })
```

In this example I would populate the ViewBag.ListofSName in the controller with the list that I want to populate the dropdown list with. Be careful the problem with this is if you have any validation in the postback and it fails you need to repopulate the ViewBag

I hope this helps.